# Probability of a Subset having 2 Consecutive Numbers

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

I'm looking for a general answer to the following issue:

You choose $k$ numbers from a set $A = \{1,2,3,...,n-1,n\}$ of size $|A|=n$. What is the probability that at least two of them are consecutive?

I know the total number of options for choosing $k$ out of $n$ is $n\choose k$, and that the total number of consecutive pairs is $n-1$ (which are $\{1,2\},\{2,3\},...,\{n-1,n\}$). But I'm not sure how to proceed.

Example:
You have a 6-digit PIN code, and you generate 5,000 **different** codes. What is the probability of getting 2 consecutive ones?

Thanks!

Comment: Hint: Pick a manageable $n$, such as $7$. For each $k$, count how many ways you can choose $k$ items that contain a pair of consecutive numbers and look for a pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You know the total number of options, so you just need to calculate the number of options with no consecutive pairs.

Hint for that: Suppose you have $k$ numbers with no two consecutive. You can order them so that $a_1<a_2<\cdots<a_k$, and then it follows (since $a_i\neq a_{i+1}-1$) that $a_1,a_2-1,\ldots,a_k-(k-1)$ are a set of $k$ distinct numbers between $1$ and $n-k+1$.